# Too much white space between figure and text

Tags: floats, vertical-alignment, columns, revtex

I am using REVTeX's APS format, so a two column document, and have not steered away from it too much. At the end of my document I have some text which just barely spills over the next page, perhaps a paragraph or so, and I follow it up with some images and that portion of the code looks something like this:

```
A bunch of text
\begin{figure}[H]
\centering
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{picture1.png}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[H]
\centering
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{picture2.png}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[H]
\centering
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{picture3.png}
\end{figure}
```

The issue I am having is that the paragraph spills over to the new page so it is near the top, but then I have a ton of white space and the first image is inserted at the very bottom of the first column. Is there anyway to cut down on the white space?

Here is my preamble:

```
\documentclass[%
 reprint,
%superscriptaddress,
%groupedaddress,
%unsortedaddress,
%runinaddress,
%frontmatterverbose, 
%preprint,
%preprintnumbers,
%nofootinbib,
%nobibnotes,
%bibnotes,
 amsmath,amssymb,
 aps,
%pra,
%prb,
%rmp,
%prstab,
%prstper,
%floatfix,
]{revtex4-2}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{dcolumn}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{array} 
\usepackage{old-arrows}
\usepackage{listliketab}
\raggedbottom
\begin{document}
```

Comment: Can you provide more detail, from `\documentclass` to `\begin{document}` so we can replicate the issue?

Comment: @Werner Yes certainly, I will update the OP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`revtex4-2`](//ctan.org/revtex) uses its own column balancing technique that isn't all that flexible. A way around it, specifically since you're working with the last page, is to insert an absurdly large strut that would fill the final (right-hand) column, leaving elements in the left-hand column to seem "ragged bottom."

[image]

```
A bunch of text
\begin{center}
  \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-a}

  \bigskip
  
  \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-b}

  \bigskip
  
  \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-c}
\end{center}

\rule{0pt}{0.9\textheight}% Overly large strut to fill final column > ragged bottom look
```

Since you're not using any `\caption`s for the last figures, just set it in a `center` environment, as just as-is as paragraphs.

Comment: Thank you for your response, I actually am using captions, I just omitted them when writing my question for simplicity.

Comment: @CBBAM: This should work the same if you use your collection of `\begin{figure}[H]`...`\end{figure}` constructions as they are set like `minipage`s (in-place and not floating). The large ending strut should work in the same way.

Comment: So use the \begin{figure} constructions within the center environment?

Comment: @CBBAM: No, just `\begin{figure}[H] <first fig> \end{figure} \begin{figure}[H] <second fig> \end{figure} \begin{figure}[H] <third fig> \end{figure} \rule{0pt}{0.9\textheight}`.

Comment: I tried that putting the \rule at the end but got another big section of white space

Comment: @CBBAM: Isn't that what you want? An unbalanced last page with images on the one side and the other blank? If you want images in both columns, then reduce the height of the strut (currently set at `0.9\textheight`).